# How to install ruby-2.2.0 not ruby-2.2.0-preview1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, rvm

I am facing some Bad::URI issue in ruby-2.2.0-preview1 so I want to downgrade with ruby-2.2.0.

I ran following commands: to uninstall `ruby-2.2.0-preview1`

> `rvm uninstall ruby-2.2.0-preview1`

then

> `rvm install ruby-2.2.0`

But its installing `ruby-2.2.0-preview1` version again.

How can I install specific version of ruby i.e. `ruby-2.2.0` ?

Comment: `rvm list known` shows you all versions of Ruby your current rvm installation knows about. Try updating it: `rvm get stable`.

Comment: Can you post terminal output from installation process?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you want to downgrade to `2.0.0`. You are mistyping `2.0.0` as `2.2.0`. Please review your request to `rvm` *very carefully*. It should be:

```
#                  ⇓
rvm install ruby-2.0.0
```

and you are trying

```
#                  ⇓
rvm install ruby-2.2.0
```

which, apparently, forces `rvm` to download the closest possible version, which is `ruby-2.2.0-preview1`.

Comment: Sorry @mudaso, it was my typo.

Comment: Then I don’t actually understand what you want to. `2.2.0 > 2.2.0-preview1`. That said, there is no ability to _downgrade_ from `2.2.0-preview1` to `2.2.0`. It would be _an upgrade_.